# Select2 jquery - How to get text in selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have input text like

```
<input type="hidden" name="xa" id="xa" data-placeholder=".." style ="width: 360px;"/>
```

and i using select2

```
$("#xa").select2({...});
```

now, i want to get text when i press 'get text'

```
$("#gettext").click(function () {
    alert($('#xa').val());  // or $('#xa').select2("val");
});
```

But it get the id of text. It's not text. How can i do it. thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it get the id of text. It's not text"? What exactly is it returning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select2` creates a `data-` attribute for internal purpose, were it stores some necessary information like `id`,`selected value` of `select2` instance. this can used to extract `selected value`.

> [Select2 Community](http://select2.github.io/select2/) : Each element instantiated as a `select2` component must contain id and text keys.

*var id  =  <s>$(test).select2('data').id</s>;*

*var seletedVal  =  <s>$(test).select2('data').text</s>;*

**Update :** With Latest version of Select2 , the object is stored in a array,so the text has to be accessed as below (`jsfiddle link updated as well`).

`$(test).select2('data')[0].text`  //instead of $(test).select2('data').text

thanks for update @DiMono

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/913nr59x/)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: sorry, but i want to get the text when i click button?

Comment: @trungkien: hey buddy, if you have found the answer, then check it as answer, it will reduce the no of open questions :)

Comment: In the current version of Select2, you must instead use `$(test).select2('data')[0].text` as `select2('data')` now returns an array that contains the object, rather than the object itself.

Comment: Thanks, DiMono. You are the only one who posted the correct answer!

Answer (score 12):

You can get the text value of the currently selected item by:

```js
$('#id').select2('data').text
```