# To get comma seperated selected text of Select2 dropdown.

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown which has a list of Regions. I need a comma seperated list of selected values.

```
 @Html.ListBox("regionSelect", regions, new { id = "regionSelect", @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
```

And the Jquery code

```
if ($('#regionSelect :selected').text() != "----------- Select Region ---------")
            var selected = $('#regionSelect :selected').text();
```

I get the result of selected as Region1Region2Region3. I can split them in terms of whenevr i see a 'R' and then insert comma in between. But I have a number of such listboxes, and I don't want to do it for each one.

Is there a generic way of doing it?

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917531/4761773) and it returned me undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the answer found in [Select2 jquery - How to get text in selectbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301052/select2-jquery-how-to-get-text-in-selectbox)

> **Update**: With Latest version of Select2 , an array objects are returned , so the text has to be accessed as below ( jsfiddle link updated as well )
>
> `$(test).select2('data')[0].text //instead of $(test).select2('data').text`

Updated Example for `multiple="multiple"`:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0st5hdzr/

Your code will be something like:

```
var selected = [];
if ($("#regionSelect").select2('data').length){
  $.each($("#regionSelect").select2('data'), function(key, item){
    selected.push(item.text);
  });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Works fine. Add a ' for $('#regionSelect) in Line 2.